# How to access Weblogic Server Entity Manager

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, weblogic, eclipselink

I have application that is deployed on Weblogic 12.1.2 and We want to use entity Manager provided by weblogic and not by org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean. I have tried below but missing some config.

Updated web.xml with PSU name

```
<persistence-context-ref>
  <persistence-context-ref-name>persistance/PSU_NAME</persistence-context-ref-name>
  <persistence-unit-name>PSU_NAME</persistence-unit-name>
</persistence-context-ref>
```

Updated application.xml with

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManagerFactory" jndi-name="persistance/PSU_NAME">
</jee:jndi-lookup>
```

On Deployment it says javax.persistence.EntityManager can't be inject. I think I am missing something.

NOTE: I know how to use org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean and its working fine.

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace? There are mutliple reasons why Spring might not be able to inject the EntityManager and the stacktrace will contain information about which it is.

Comment: If the jndi lookup fails, you can do a manual lookup in your own bean, to try out which name the entityManagerFactory is registered on. Speaking of which: are you sure, persistance/PSU_NAME is not a typo and should be persist*e*nce/PSU_NAME

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by

```
<persistence-context-ref>
  <persistence-context-ref-name>PSU_NAME</persistence-context-ref-name>
  <persistence-unit-name>PSU_NAME</persistence-unit-name>
</persistence-context-ref>
```

and

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="emf" jndi-name="PSU_NAME" />
```

and **xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"**